# java.lang.NullPointerException with GeoServer and Postgis

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, xml

I am continuing work that another person began based on Geoserver and postgis. On the database level there are many tables and the layers are views based on these tables. That is working great!

Now I want to create some other tables and views. I have also been adding them to GeoServer. In order to check if this is working I selected the `Layer Preview` opyion and I clicked on `Open Layer` in the `Common Formats` column. The result is that a popup is displayed to download an XML file, but when I open it, it says:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
    <ServiceException> java.lang.NullPointerException null </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

For the layers created by the other person, this works fine. I compared two layers and they seem to be similar, so what am I doing wrong?

PS: All layers are converted from shapefiles to postgis.

Comment: Check the 'Layer style' at first..

Comment: The "solution" cant be made since the "status" page on geoserver only show the bug report where teh last notified is "java.lang.NullPointerException"
If I dont have a direct/vpn/remote desktop to the server machine..how I could fix it?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution was go to option `server state -> reload` and that is all.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted solution, so that future readers with the same problem will know what worked. Thanks.

Comment: GeoKevin, I can accept it tomorrow due to platform restriction.

Comment: Understood. Thanks (in advance) for accepting it, and thereby keeping the site running well.